# Retrying Eclipse ADT for Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I just started trying to learn Android this morning, and got up to here before encountering problems.  http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

I'm trying to install the ADT for eclipse.  The first time I tried, I went through all the steps and while it was downloading everything in step 6, it froze and gave me an error.  So I stopped and went back to retry, but now it gives me a duplicate location error.

I'm tempted to just delete Eclipse and start over, because I can't find where the current manifestation of Android is so I can delete it and try again.

My version of Eclipse is: 3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY

Comment: The ADT plugin depends on some eclipse features that are not preinstalled on every version of eclipse. Which "flavor" did you [download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)? Both "Eclipse Classic" and "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" should come with the required depencies. And which error did you get?

Comment: When I click "About Eclipse" it says Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, so I would assume that one.

Comment: Yes that is a correct version that I use on a regular basis. Any chance that you remember the error? In general there is also no problem with deleting the whole eclipse folder and starting over if you have time.

Comment: I don't remember exactly.  It said that something else was being used.  I was downloading some Android docs at the same time so that may have been it.  Isn't there a way to just go in and delete everything related to Android on Eclipse and start over?

Comment: You can go to `Help -> Install new Software`, click `Whats already installed?` and see if anything starting with "Android" is installed. If this is the case, select it and press "Uninstall" at the bottom.

Comment: All it had was the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers.  The Installation History didn't have any record of my attempt to install Android either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my installation steps i do when preparing for android development.

I would just delete everything you have done so far and start over. It should not take long and you will at least know that you have done everything right and have nothing messing you up from what you have done already.

1. download/install [java jdk](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u2-download-1377129.html)
2. download [eclipse classic](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-371/indigosr1)
3. launch eclipse and go to `help -> install new software` and in the box type in the following "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" then download the correct stuff there.
4. Now after 3 is done, you should now have `window -> android sdk manager` click on that.
5. Now select the stuff you want from the sdk manager and install.

This should be enough to get you going, let me know if you have any other trouble!

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up just deleting Eclipse and adding the newest one, and then updating everything Java-related on my computer to the newest version.  Overkill, sure, but at least now when I have a problem I'll know it's my fault.